# Plotting sin(1/x)

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I am trying to learn how to plot sin and cos functions, and with this assingment:
$$
\sin{\frac{1}{x}}
$$

I am stuck, because I dont know how to calculate period(or is it even possible), because the period is always changing.

My question is, is it possible to calculate the period, I dont want to calculate every zero point for every period, so is it possible to calculate the rate of change of the length of the period.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is good to note that $|f(x)|\leq1$ so it is bounded by $y=-1,~y=+1$. In fact, because of its nature, while $x$ approaches the origin, the function undergoes more and more oscillations between $+1,-1$. Also it doesn't have a limit at $x=0$. I think the rest is to find some points in $xy-$ plane and make a plot. Here, it a plot done by Maple:

[image]

Comment: @qwr: Thanks for your consideration to my small attempt. :-)

Comment: @amWhy: I'll tell you soon. ;-)

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: thanks for your consideration.  I am working on my final thesis.  :-)

Comment: The graph shows it clearly, but is there any intuitive way to understand why the function oscillates infinitely?

Answer (score 2):

Since near $x=0$ the function goes wild, you can't hope that it is periodic...
Take the sequences $a_n=\frac{1}{\pi/2+2\pi k}, b_n=\frac{1}{3\pi/2+2\pi k}$ and watch what happens.

For plotting graphs, it is always useful to consult W|A: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sin%281%2Fx%29 .

Comment: Thanks for fast reply. I know how the function looks like, but I was hoping there is some logical stepping between zero points on the x axis.

Comment: The zeros are precisely $x=\frac{1}{\pi k}$, so I don't understand your question.

Comment: Well $\sin(1/x)=0$ precisely when $1/x=n\pi$ for an integer $n$, i.e., for $x=\pi/n$.

Comment: Now is everything clear. Thanks guys.